# Avoiding HVAC fan re-evaporating condensation

Tags: hvac

I'd like to be able to run my (central) HVAC in fan-on mode rather than auto to keep air circulating so that temperature equalizes better (for comfort and better thermostat response). However, whenever I do, it undoes all the dehumidification work it just did running air over the condensation it took out of the air and re-evaporating it. Humidity is noticably (and unacceptably) higher.

Is there a way to adjust the drain/trap so this doesn't happen without interfering with the (obviously necessary) role of the trap?

Comment: I think you are overestimating the extent to which it "undoes all the work" - only water that has not yet dripped off the coil and run down the drain, and the very small surface area in the trap itself would be available fore evaporating. Any that has condensed, dripped off, and made it down the drain is not there to evaporate. Pictures of the trap arrangement might suggest reconfigurations, or perhaps you have an outside air intake that needs to be closed during recirculation.

Comment: There is no outside air intake, and it does get very humid.

Comment: Is the drain clogged? Are there large puddles of water that don't make it into the drain inside your ductwork?

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Yeah thinking about it more, I'm guessing it has standing water that's not draining, whether from partial clog or mis-leveled surface or something. I guess I'lll open it up and check it out..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's the nature of refrigeration-based cooling. Water vapor condenses onto the evaporator coil while the coil's temperature is below the dew point; when the refrigeration stops and the coil's temperature rises above the dew point, the remaining liquid on the coil evaporates into the air.

There might be some things you can do to make this less perceptible, though.

During a cooling cycle liquid water forms on the surface of the coil. It's just like an iced beverage sitting on the countertop: a light film of water forms, then we begin to see individual droplets, and soon the droplets grow large enough that  they run down the glass (or can, bottle, whatever).

##### Is your evaporator coil working like a sponge?

If the evaporator coil is dirty (with lint, dust, etc that bypassed the filter) then those materials act like a sponge. They can increase the amount of liquid water that can be held on the coil rather than running away to the drain. That's water that will re-evaporate into your air. So make sure your evaporator coil is clean.

##### How long does a cooling cycle run?

A big factor is the length of a cooling cycle. Think about that iced beverage again; imagine that your goal is to make as large a puddle on the countertop as you can. You could:

1. Set the beverage on the counter. As soon as droplets begin to run down the glass, wipe it dry with a cloth and move the glass into the refrigerator for 5 minutes. Repeat.
2. Set the beverage on the counter. Leave it there, undisturbed, until all the ice cubes have melted. Then wipe the glass dry with a cloth, move into the refrigerator for 10 minutes, add ice, repeat.

Obviously #2 will make a much bigger puddle. When an HVAC system operates like approach #1 we call that "short cycling." The HVAC is unable to de-humidify the space because hardly any liquid water is shed off the coil by the time the system reaches its temperature setpoint and shuts down. Approach #2, in which the cooling system runs for long stretches, allows the system to remove a significant amount of humidity.

Measure how much time elapses from the moment when the HVAC turns on until the first drop of condensate falls out. That's how much cooling effort is "wasted" getting the coil wet, only to be dried into the house again later. Compare that to the length of the entire cooling cycle. I'd think you want the whole cycle to be at least twice as long as that wetting period, but longer is better. Reducing the cooling capacity, so that a cycle has to run longer, will increase dehumidification.

##### Modify how fan-on is done

Some thermostats have a "minimum fan runtime per hour" setting (Ecobee, to name one). The use of this setting, rather than fan-always-on, could allow the fan to be off for a few minutes immediately after a cooling cycle. That would allow time for the water on the coil to evaporate more slowly, which might make the rise in humidity less perceptible to you.

Some furnaces/air handlers can be configured so that the fan-on setting runs the blower at a lower speed than what's used for cooling. This too could help reduce that humidity spike perception after each cooling cycle.